# How can I solve codeforces 121A?

Tags: c++, recursion

I've tried to solve codeforces problem 121A

http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/121/A

but it gives me Time Limit Exceeded on test 14

What I came up with was Generating all possible lucky numbers till the range  10^9 then evaluating the next() of all the numbers in the given range by looking for it in the possibilities then I sum them up. I know it's an inefficient way but can I modify anything to improve the complexity? Any Suggestions?

here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

long long int Next(long long int x, vector <long long int> vec , int &i){
    for (i ; i < vec.size(); i++){
        if (vec[i] >= x){
            return vec[i];
        }
    }
}
void Generate(int size, vector <long long int> &v , string s = "" ){
    if (size == 0){
        long long int intStr = strtoll(s.c_str(), NULL, 10);
        v.push_back(intStr);

        return;
    }
    Generate(size - 1,v, s + "4");
    Generate(size - 1,v, s + "7");
}
long long int Sum(long long int l, long long int r,vector <long long int> vec){
    long long int sum = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (long long int i = l; i <= r; i++){
        sum += Next(i,vec,index);
    }
    return sum;
}
int main(){

        long long int l, r;
        cin >> l >> r;
        vector <long long int> vec;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            Generate(i,vec,"");
        }


        cout << Sum(l, r, vec);


}
```

Comment: When you profiled your program, what function is most of the execution spent in?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think most of the execution is spent in functions (Sum) and (Next)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `Next()` function in your code. Just modify the Sum function and it runs in about `30 ms` time. First sort the lucky numbers in ascending order. Suppose `x` is the first lucky number which is `>=l and <=r`. So `x` will be the `next()` value for all numbers in range `[l,x]`. We have `x-l+1` such numbers and they will add `(x-l+1)*x` to sum. After we add this to the `sum`, `x` now becomes new `l`. Continue this process until `x>r` at which point we add `(r-l+1)*x` to `sum`.

Code:

```
long long int Sum(long long int l, long long int r, vector <long long int> vec){
    long long int sum=0;
    int index=0;
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for(long long int i=0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        if(vec[i]>=l && vec[i]<=r) {
            sum+=(vec[i]-l+1)*vec[i];
            l=vec[i]+1;
        }
        else if(vec[i]>=l && vec[i]>r) {
            sum+=(r-l+1)*vec[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Next` always searches for the next value from the beginning of the list; once you have found the first number to go in your summation, you shouldn't need to do any more searching.

Note that you generate the *whole* list, no matter how little of it you need.

And you build up strings only to parse them into numbers when generating the list, which is probably slower than just doing simple arithmetic instead.

Generate seems to repeat a lot of work; for example, has to re-generate all of the numbers with 9 digits to get those with 10.

Comment: yes I just adjusted that but it still doesn't run in less than 2 seconds ? is there any other thing that I can do?

Comment: Depends on how you "adjusted" it.

Comment: I just edited my code check out both sum and next functions

Answer (score 0):

I have a python implementation which uses the same concept for the sum function but you can implement a next function which runs in `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the number. The code is as follows.

```
def next(n,k):
 s = n
 n = int(n)

 if int("4"*k)>=n:
    return "4"*k
 elif int("7"*k)<n:
    return "4"*(k+1)
 elif 4<int(s[0])<7:
    return "7"+"4"*(k-1)
 if not s[1:]=="":
    a = next(s[1:],k-1)
    if s[0]=="4":

        if len(str(a))==k:
            return "7"+a[1:]
        else:
            return "4"+a
    else:
            return "7"+a
 else:
    return "7"
```

here `n` is in string format and `k` is the length of that string.